# How can i mask user input when telneting?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a socket application.  The socket for the client connection uses a NetworkStream which does not allow seeking.

So, how can i mask user input when they telnet to my socket server since NetworkStream does not provide seeking?

1.) It needs to work with 3rd party telnet, ie: im not creating the telnet client
2.) I can settle for nothing being shown in the telnet client, but prefer masking

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "masking"?

Comment: When user types a character, show * instead

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume that you're taking advantage of local echo here (which telnet clients do by default.)  The telnet protocol has an out-of-band control command structure that you can use to toggle this (see [RFC 854](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html)).  In particular, you're going to want to turn local echo off briefly, so the user's telnet client does not simply put the characters on the screen.  You can do this by sending the IAC WON'T ECHO command when you want their client to stop displaying characters then sending the IAC WILL ECHO command to start again (see [RFC 857](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc857.html).)

Basically, you just need to send three bytes:  0xFF 0xFC 0x01 to turn echo off, and three bytes:  0xFF 0xFB 0x01 to turn echo back on.

If you want, while you've turned echo off, you could send a '*' character to the user for every character you read.  This will give them the indication that their characters are being received, although for passwords, I prefer to give no echo at all.

Comment: Shouldn't that have been `IAC DO ECHO / DONT ECHO`?

Comment: Actually, rereading RFC 857, I think that the server should send WILL ECHO, which informs the client that IT (the server) will be providing echo (implying that the client should stop.)  And then it should send WON'T ECHO, telling the client that it will stop echoing (and thus the client should do local echo again.)

Answer (score 3):

The Telnet protocol can support both "local echo" and "remote echo". Normally these days, everything is done with remote echo (this better supports interactive line editing features). That means the *server* is responsible for sending back to the client what was typed, so that the client can display it on the screen.

Therefore, to support "masking", then either:

- send back something like `*` for each character typed
- don't send anything back to the client when they type their password